# Show that if A is self-adjoint and $A^{n}= I$ then $A^{2}=I$

Tags: linear-algebra

>
If $A$ is a self-adjoint linear transformation on the finite-dimensional inner
product space such that $A^{n}=I$ for some positive integer $n$, proof that
$A^2=I$.

Comment: What do you know about self-adjoint transformations? Are they all diagonalisable? What do you know about their eigenvalues?

Comment: yes, we have the spectral theorem

Comment: What field is it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

>
       Let we use the spectral decomposition theorem to write, $A$ as 
        $A=\sum \lambda_{i}E_{i}$ and as $A$ is self-adjoint all its eigenvalues are
        real, but $A^{n}=\sum\lambda_{i}^{n}E_{i}$ now suppose that for some 
    $n\in
        \mathbb{N}$ we have $A^{n}=1$ or just 
        \begin{eqnarray*}
           A^{n}=\lambda_{1}^{n}E_{1}+...+\lambda_{k}^{n}E_{k}=1=
           E_{1}+...+E_{k}
        \end{eqnarray*}
    then by the uniqueness of the decomposition we can write that
    $\lambda_{i}^{n}=1,~i=1,2,...,k$, now if $n$ is odd 
    $\lambda_{i}=1$ ( and so $A$ has only one eigenvalue ) and if $n$ is 
    even $\lambda_{i}=\pm1\Rightarrow \lambda_{i}^{2}=1,~i=1,2,...,k$ 
    ( in this case $A$ has at most two eigenvalues ) and in both cases we have
        $$ A^{2}=\lambda_{1}^{2}E_{1}+...+\lambda_{k}^{2}E_{k}=
           E_{1}+...+E_{k}=1$$